# Controller test: "ShoppingList.count" didn't change by 1. Expected: 3 Actual: 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I test the controlller "shopping_list". However when I start the test I get this error:

```
Failure:
ShoppingListsControllerTest#test_should_create_shopping_list [C:/Users/Clemens/meindorfladen/Server/test/controllers/shopping_lists_controller_test.rb:30]:
"ShoppingList.count" didn't change by 1.
Expected: 3
  Actual: 2
```

So one parameter is missing, but how can this be? Does somebody know the answer? Here is the code:
**shopping_lists.yml**

```
shopping_list_drogerie:
 user: user_heiko
 name: Drogerie
 created_at: <%= Time.now %>
 updated_at: <%= Time.now %>

shopping_list_lebensmittel:
 user: user_schmitt
 name: Lebensmittel
 created_at: <%= Time.now %>
 updated_at: <%= Time.now %>
```

**db/schema**

```
 create_table "shopping_lists", force: :cascade, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8" do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string   "name"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_shopping_lists_on_user_id", using: :btree
  end
```

**models/shopping_list.rb**

```
class ShoppingList < ApplicationRecord
  # db associations
  belongs_to :user
  # if a shopping list is deleted, also delete information about all items on the list
  has_many :list_items, :dependent => :destroy
  # if a shopping list is deleted, also delete information about who it was shared with
  has_many :shared_lists , :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :shared_with_users,through: :shared_lists, :source => :user

  has_many :invitation
  has_one :appointment

  # validations
  validates :user, :presence => true
  validates :name, presence: true, allow_blank: false, uniqueness: {scope: :user_id}
end
```

**controllers/shopping_lists_controller.rb**

```
class ShoppingListsController < ApplicationController
  load_and_authorize_resource

  # GET /shopping_lists/1
  # GET /shopping_lists/1.json
  def show
  end

  # POST /shopping_lists
  # POST /shopping_lists.json
  def create
    respond_to do |format|
      if @shopping_list.save
        format.html { redirect_to shopping_list_list_items_path(@shopping_list), alert: 'Shopping list was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @shopping_list }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @shopping_list.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /shopping_lists/1
  # PATCH/PUT /shopping_lists/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @shopping_list.update(shopping_list_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @shopping_list, notice: 'Shopping list was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @shopping_list }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @shopping_list.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /shopping_lists/1
  # DELETE /shopping_lists/1.json
  def destroy
      @shopping_list.destroy
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to shopping_lists_url, notice: 'Shopping list was successfully destroyed.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      end
   end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_shopping_list
      @shopping_list = ShoppingList.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
   private def shopping_list_params
      params.require(:shopping_list).permit(:name)
   end
end
```

EDIT: sorry I forgot the test-controller: **shopping_lists_controller_test**

```
require 'test_helper'

class ShoppingListsControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  include Devise::Test::IntegrationHelpers
  include Warden::Test::Helpers

  setup do
    @drogerieShoppingList = shopping_lists(:shopping_list_drogerie)
    @heiko = users(:user_heiko)
    @heikoAppointment = appointments(:appointment_heiko)
  end

  test "should get index" do
    login_as(@heiko)
    @heiko.confirmed_at = Time.now
    get shopping_lists_url
    assert_response :success
  end

  test "should get new" do
    login_as(@heiko)
    @heiko.confirmed_at = Time.now
    get new_shopping_list_url
    assert_response :success
  end

  test "should create shopping_list" do
    login_as(@heiko)
    @heiko.confirmed_at = Time.now
    assert_difference('ShoppingList.count') do
      #post shopping_lists_url, params: { shopping_list: @drogerieShoppingList.attributes, user_id:  @heiko.id, appointment: @heikoAppointment }
      post shopping_lists_url, params: { shopping_list: @drogerieShoppingList.attributes }
    end

    assert_redirected_to shopping_list_url(ShoppingList.last)
  end

  test "should show shopping_list" do
    login_as(@heiko)
    @heiko.confirmed_at = Time.now
    get shopping_list_url(@drogerieShoppingList)
    assert_response :success
  end

  test "should get edit" do
    login_as(@heiko)
    @heiko.confirmed_at = Time.now
    get edit_shopping_list_url(@drogerieShoppingList)
    assert_response :success
  end

  test "should update shopping_list" do
    login_as(@heiko)
    @heiko.confirmed_at = Time.now
    patch shopping_list_url(@drogerieShoppingList), params: { shopping_list: {name: 'WochenendEinkauf'  } }
    assert_redirected_to shopping_list_url(@drogerieShoppingList)
  end

  test "should destroy shopping_list" do
    login_as(@heiko)
    @heiko.confirmed_at = Time.now
    assert_difference('ShoppingList.count', -1) do
      delete shopping_list_url(@drogerieShoppingList)
    end

    assert_redirected_to shopping_lists_url
  end
end
```

Comment: I just posted almost the same question. I think the problem is with the fixtures. check myapp/test/fixtures/MODEL_HERE.yml. Your schema shows you have t.integer "user_id" as well as index_shopping_lists_on_user_id. You can look into the two too.

Answer (score 1):

The problem isn't about the number of parameters.

Add the controller test code, because there's a test case that fails.

But when I look closer to your controller, the `create` method didn't actually created a `@schopping_list`. It just tries to save a @shopping_list variable which can easily be a **`nil`**.

UPDATE:

There seems to be two issues:

1. `#create` action in controller

   The @sopping_list isn't initialized at all, You have to build the @shopping_list model before saving it. Like this:

   `def create
     @shopping_list =  SoppingList.new(shopping_list_params)
     respond_to do |format|
       if @shopping_list.save
       ...`
2. Don't know whether the `name` field is the only field required to create a SoppingList model. As I see you've permitted only that one:

   > `params.require(:shopping_list).permit(:name)`

Comment: thanks for your answer, I added the code of the controller-test of shopping-list. Would you have a look on this?

Comment: does somebody else know whats wrong with the parameters?

Comment: I just posted almost the same question. I think the problem is with the fixtures. check `myapp/test/fixtures/MODEL_HERE.yml`

Comment: Your schema shows you have `t.integer  "user_id"` as well as `index_shopping_lists_on_user_id`. You can look into the two too.